# Resize background image on IE

Tags: html, css

I need to center some image as background of my website, this works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on IE the image can't resize with the browser size...

If i resize the window, the image resize too in chrome and firefox.. but not on IE

take a look: http://www.alsite.com.br/misskessi

and this is my css:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #FFFFFF url(../imagens/fundo_site2.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center
}
```

any tips?

Comment: To call the image should your code be: `background: #FFFFFF url('../imagens/fundo_site2.jpg');` maybe this is why IE will not pick it up?

Comment: nop.. don't need to use quotation marks...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not something IE supports (in older versions at least) and you would need to use JavaScript as the solution. There are plugins around such as [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) but from looking at your site, this may not be the perfect solution for you. I hope this helps.